# Phpmyadmin error 500 - can't load anything

Tags: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin, whm

I was trying to do a right join of two tables, but it seems like it was too much information or the syntax was wrong and then the page froze so I closed out of it.  But when I tried to reload PHPmyadmin, it shows everything in red and nothing will load.  I tried restarting the server but it's the same.

Is there anyway to reset it or something?  Websites still load/access the database fine, it's just phpmyadmin seems to be blocked now?

It says

> **Cannot use a scalar value as an array**
>   Error in processing request
>   Error code: 500
>   Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
>   It seems that the connection to server has been lost.
>   Please check your network connectivity and server status.

[image: Screenshot: phpmyadmin error 500]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please use latest 5.0 version and open an issue on our Github tracker

Comment: I know that issue exists but never succeed to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

Just clear cookies for localhost or the domain phpMyAdmin is using in your browser. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: that was frustrating, I thought I broke my database...